# how do i set up a tor relay on windows 10 NT

Tags: relays, windows

how easy is it to setup a tor relay on windows 10 NT?
Can someone point me in the right direct in setting it up on this OS?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you install Linux? Easier

Comment: i currently have the linux subsystem for windows.

Comment: you can _try_ following the instructions for Linux in wsl but I don't know if it'll work

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorRelayGuide) you should be able to get it done. Just ignore OS specific information

Please note you must keep the browser open the **ENTIRE** time you want the relay running